# Why Spring DataSourceTransactionManager suppress the concurrent number of ActiveMQ consumer

Tags: spring, concurrency, activemq-classic

I got one strange problem.
when I config a DataSourceTransactionManager with spring xml, the concurrent consumers of ActiveMQ were suppressed whatever I change "maxConcurrentConsumers" property value. I have 5 queues, the total concurrent consumers of all 5 queue always kept at 8.

if I remove DataSourceTransactionManager bean, each queue's concurrent consumers reached the max number 5 declared in "maxConcurrentConsumers" .

The DataSourceTransactionManager work for dataSource, i cannot understand why it affected to ActiveMQ.

version:

- Spring 3.2.5.RELEASE
- ActiveMq 5.9.0

application.xml

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driver}" />
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.user}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
</bean>

<!-- once I add this, activemq total consumers always kept at 8  -->
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<!-- activemq consumer connection -->
<bean id="consumerConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.pool.PooledConnectionFactory"
    destroy-method="stop">
    <property name="connectionFactory">
        <bean class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
            <property name="brokerURL">
                <value>tcp://localhost:61616</value>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="maxConnections" value="5"></property>
</bean>

<!-- i have 5 queues -->
<bean id="test_1" class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue">
    <constructor-arg index="0" value="test_1}" />
</bean>
<bean id="test_2" class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue">
    <constructor-arg index="0" value="test_2}" />
</bean>
<bean id="test_3" class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue">
    <constructor-arg index="0" value="test_3}" />
</bean>
<bean id="test_4" class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue">
    <constructor-arg index="0" value="test_4}" />
</bean>
<bean id="test_5" class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue">
    <constructor-arg index="0" value="test_5}" />
</bean>

<!-- consumer listener container -->
<bean id="testOneMessageListenerContainer"
    class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="consumerConnectionFactory"></property>
    <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="1" />
    <property name="maxConcurrentConsumers" value="5" />
    <property name="destination" ref="test_1"></property>
    <property name="messageListener" ref="demoBusinessListener"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="testTwoMessageListenerContainer"
    class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="consumerConnectionFactory"></property>
    <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="1" />
    <property name="maxConcurrentConsumers" value="5" />
    <property name="destination" ref="test_2"></property>
    <property name="messageListener" ref="demoBusinessListener"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="testThreeMessageListenerContainer"
    class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="consumerConnectionFactory"></property>
    <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="1" />
    <property name="maxConcurrentConsumers" value="5" />
    <property name="destination" ref="test_3"></property>
    <property name="messageListener" ref="demoBusinessListener"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="testFourMessageListenerContainer"
    class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="consumerConnectionFactory"></property>
    <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="1" />
    <property name="maxConcurrentConsumers" value="5" />
    <property name="destination" ref="test_4"></property>
    <property name="messageListener" ref="demoBusinessListener"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="testFiveMessageListenerContainer"
    class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="consumerConnectionFactory"></property>
    <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="1" />
    <property name="maxConcurrentConsumers" value="5" />
    <property name="destination" ref="test_5"></property>
    <property name="messageListener" ref="demoBusinessListener"></property>
</bean>
```

can someone help me!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after some test, i found a way to resolve this problem.
when i change the dataSource "maxActive" parameter to a number greater than sum of all mq listener maxConcurrentConsumers. it work fine.

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driver}" />
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.user}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
    <property name="maxActive" value="120" />
</bean>
```

it seems that the max number of activemq listener thread affected by Datasource maxActive parameter

Comment: It confused a lot. Any future investigation?